# django model manytomany filter by count

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many

I have 2 models that have a one to many relationships. I'm trying to reflect blog by the number of likes on a blog. I tried to filter num_likes than annotate by count, but none of it reflects blogs by the number of likes.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_content = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "likes")
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name = "likes")
```

I expect to reflect blogs on my template order by the number of likes each of them have.

Comment: "I tried to filter num_likes than annotate by count" - what did you try, what did you expect to get, and what did you get?

Comment: there  is no `manytomanyfield` here